# "Ъ" в старой азбуке

Tags: алфавит

По каким принципам до реформы русского языка употреблялся твердый знак?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Он писался в нескольких случаях:
-На конце слов, если те не заканчивались на гласную, Й или Ь.
-В качестве разделительного знака между приставкой и корнем и заменят апостроф (как и в современном языке).
-В отдельных словах: въслѣдъ, обезъяна, другъдруга,.
Иногда Ъ мог быть в значении звука О, что и сейчас сохранилось в болгарском языке.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIR, в конце не всех слов, а только заимствованных. Но утверждать не берусь.

Answer (score 0):

Уточню. Говоря об отдельных словах, надо четко обозначать период, о котором идёт речь. 
Написание через Ъ слов типа подьячiй и обезьяна всегда было ошибкой, о чем и упоминает Грот. В словах типа "другъдруга" и "въслѣдъ" до середины XIX века наблюдались колебания, единых и всеобщих нормативных правил не было (как ни странно, аж до 1956 г.) С появлением орфографического свода Грота большинство неопределенностей было устранено. В большинстве случаев Ъ **между согласными** на стыке приставки и корня исчез. Остался он перед дефисом, хотя сам Грот выступал за его отмену.
Кроме того, было несколько иностранных слов (типа адъюнкт), где Ъ считался корневым и поэтому не был затронут реформой. Некоторые из них сохранили подбное написание до настоящего времени.